# Extend VeraCrypt Container Size

Tags: filesystems, veracrypt

Suppose I have created a 1 GiB VeraCrypt container and now have it filled to 900 MiB.

How can I extend the container to 5 GiB on Ubuntu?

(without having to create a new 5 GiB container and then copying the files over)

Following the advice of pbies, I created a 5 MiB VeraCrypt container (with a normal and hidden partition).

I used `dd if=/dev/zero bs=5M count=1 >> File` to append 5 MiB of null bytes

Running `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/veracrypt1`, I get an error:

```
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/veracrypt1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

I made sure to use EXT4 as the filesystem (rather than FAT, as `resize2fs` cannot operate on it)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add 4GB of zero-bytes at the end of the container and then after connecting it in VeraCrypt - resizing the partition inside.

Create 4GB file of zero-bytes using `dd` and `/dev/zero`, `cat` it by `>>` at the end of the container, then mount the drive and use `resize2fs` to make it bigger.

If there are hidden partitions in container you may loose them. Backup your data first!

EDIT: After adding 4GB at the end of file, you need to run fdisk and resize the partition (remove it and create it but bigger, no data loss in this process - it only operates on partition table).

EDIT2: It is not safe solution for extending a partition with container. Resizing a container should be tested if it works, as data may be lost!
See https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/c011ff54/?page=1&limit=25#361a

To be safe use VeraCryptExpander.exe on Windows. There may be a file system access problem (if it is ext4).

Comment: @7Fwt7jmMuyR5BZd see my edit.

Comment: By doing this, would the container no longer be encrypted / filled with random data?

Comment: No; It would be encrypted

Comment: @7Fwt7jmMuyR5BZd it would be filled with random data but usable.

Comment: But didn't we just fill it with zeros (or would it be because VeraCrypt encrypts it while writing to the container)? Anyways, I'll go ahead and try it on a test container

Comment: We fill it with zeroes so it will be treated as random data for encrypting functions in VC. Really it doesn't matter what data you add to the container.

Comment: If you encrypt a region of space on the hdd and its filled with 0s when you encrypt the 0s you end up with a bunch of 0s....it's only after you fill that space up with actual data will it be random noise....

Comment: Doesn't this method destroy the backup header at the end of the veracrypt volume?

Comment: @kdb This happens only for hidden volume.

Comment: @pbies Hidden volumes shouldn't be relevant here. From the documentation, the hidden-volume header is at a fixed reserved position at the start of the container and shouldn't be affected by the resize (though the hidden-volume contents may be). The backup header for both standard and hidden volume is positioned at a fixed offset relative to the *end* of the container, so VeraCrypt should no longer find it after the described resize operation, or any other operation that changes the file-size.

Comment: @kdb I don't know anything about header at the end of container for non-hidden volumes. Any source for that info?

Comment: @pbies Best source for this is [the Veracrypt Volume Format Specification](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/VeraCrypt%20Volume%20Format%20Specification.html): *"Each VeraCrypt volume contains an embedded backup header, located at the end of the volume."* (details see link).

Comment: @kbd Yes, I can see there "Backup header for hidden volume" in the table, seems like not strict info if this is only for hidden volume or not. OP should test if the solution works in the end = no problems with mount process.

Comment: Someone reported breaking their volume using this solution: https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/c011ff54/?page=1&limit=25#361a I think we need something else.

Comment: @IvanPerez for container it should be fine (depending on where is the backup header stored, would need to check if it is at the end of the container), person has resized outer partition. Some would need to check this solution.